# How to save Multiple Selection data in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

Can anyone please help me how to save multiple selection in the `DB`?

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select id="tag_list" name="tag_list[]" class="form-control" multiple></select>  
</div>
```

Controller function is like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $comics = new Comic();

    $tags = $request->input('tag_list');

    $comics->appreance = implode(',', $tags);
    $comics->save();

    return redirect('/comic');
}
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with this code?

Comment: drop here the html for the options of your select  and i will tell you

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not clear enough how you save your `tags or appearance`, i `assume` it save one tag in a `single` row. If that's the case then you can do something like

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

        $tags = $request->input('tag_list');
        foreach($tags as $tag){
          $comics = new Comic();
          $comics->appreance = tag;
          $comics->save();
       }

        return redirect('/comic');
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried json?

Try this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $comic = new Comic();

    $tags = $request->input('tag_list');

    $comic->appreance = json_encode($tags);
    $comic->save();

    return redirect('/comic');
}
```

But I'll suggest to consider separate table for tags and create a relationship for comic and tags.

Take a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Answer (score -1):

You can use Bootstrap select to choose multiple select.

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Ekd8P